# AVAssetDownloadDelegate methods for HLS getting called before I pause AVplayer

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

i have this code that supposed to download the audio stream and by pressing pause the download shoud stop

```
func setupAssetDownload() {

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "downloadIdentifier")
    let downloadSession=AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: configuration, assetDownloadDelegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let url = NSURL(string: "http: ... stream url")
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url as! URL)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let downloadTask = downloadSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset,assetTitle: "downloadedAudio",assetArtworkData: nil,options: nil)
        downloadTask?.resume()
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: (downloadTask?.urlAsset)!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

}
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(location.relativePath, forKey: "assetPath")
    print("Done")
}
```

but when I launch the app ,it already shows "Done".
I'm using radio stream URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVAssetDownloadURLSession is for downloading the asset. If you just want to play it you AVPlayer can handle that.

Alternatively if you want to cancel the download you can call `downloadTask.cancel()`